# How to sepearate UITableVIew's UIScrollDelegate & UITableVIewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have written a custom view based on `UITableView` and I want to do something based on `UIScrollViewDelegate`, so I set the `tableView`'s `delegate` to `self` (custom view), but if I do this the `UITableVIewDelegate` is set to  `self` (custom view) too, implying that I can't let the `controllers` (containing this `tableView`) to do things like `tableView:didSelectCell` and other similar things. Can I set the `UIScrollDelegate` to `self` and still let the `UITableVIewDelegate` methods to be called by others?

Answer (score 0):

Because `UITableViewDelegate` extends `UIScrollViewDelegate`, you cannot separate that as you want. However, you can declare your own `customDelegate` property and fire required methods again after your handlers in custom view

Comment: i was thinking that can I use sth like forwardInvocation to achieve this , if it's a uiscrollviewdelegate method call self ,if it's a uitableviewdelegate method ,call other object , is this possible?

Comment: What will be the `target` of you `NSInvocation`? You are attempting to assign two separate objects to one property)

Comment: in fact ,i met a problem here , if i set the tableview's delegate to self , and i print the - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector ,i  found only uiscrollviewdelegate's method called , uitableviewdelegate not called in respondsToSelector